# How the compiled version of this toy language pseudocode would work in assembly roughly?

Tags: function, assembly, calling-convention, nested-function

I am working on a toy language which is need of some compilation now. So far, I have nested function calls, and I am wondering what the assembly sort of pseudocode would look like. This includes:

- Function prologue and epilogue.
- Instruction "blocks".
- How functions are reused.
- Not real assembly code, just pseudocode (though I am sort of coming from x86).

The x86 "block" structure I'm referring to seems to be this:

```
my_function:
  enter N, 0
  ; ... details
  leave
  ret
```

To keep it simple (avoiding async and all that), my toy code looks like this basically:

```
my_func_a(add(1, my_func_z(2, 3)), sub(my_func_r(4, 5, 6), 7), 8)
```

Or spread out:

```
my_func_a(
  add(
    1,
    my_func_z(2, 3)
  ),
  sub(
    my_func_r(
      4,
      5,
      6
    ),
    7
  ),
  8
)
```

When I try to translate this mentally into some sort of corresponding pseudo-assembly, I end up doing this:

```
u = my_func_r(4, 5, 6)
v = sub(u, 7)
w = my_func_z(2, 3)
x = add(1, w)
y = my_func_a(x, v) ; final result
```

I'm not sure if I got the order exactly correct, but it's close I think. But this isn't quite low-level enough as x86, so I try lowering it further:

```
mov r1, 4
mov r2, 5
mov r3, 6
call my_func_r
; how to capture the "u = ..."?
mov r1, u?
mov r2, 7
call sub
; how about capturing "v"?
mov r1, 2
mov r2, 3
call my_func_z
; w = ... somehow
mov r1, 1
mov r2, w
call add
; x = ... somehow
mov r1, x
mov r2, v
call my_func_a
; y...
```

*I would try and use some sort of tool to compile some rough C-like language into LLVM, for example, but it's way over my head to get that all going and working at this stage.*

Now let's say we have implementations for some of these functions:

```
my_func_r(a,b,c):
  enter ...
  add a, b
  sub b, c
  leave
  ret

my_func_z(a,b):
  enter ...
  ; ...
  leave
  ret

my_func_a(a,b):
  enter ...
  ; ...
  leave
  ret
```

Basically what I'm wondering is, *how should the final pseudocode be written*? (given I haven't exactly specified here how everything works, just got it at a rough level at this point). What would it roughly look like? I don't see how the values are properly placed and passed around in the lowest-level Assembly version.

- Where are the *arguments* passed into the functions? At what place, before the function call, or inside the function/block?
- How do you capture the output variables outside of the function?

Sorry if this pseudocode is prone with errors, I am just beginning to put the pieces together, so please be gentle.

Comment: A nested-function pointer also needs a pointer to the parent scope's stack frame so it can reference variables in that parent scope.  (as well as the code address).  I think this is called a "static chain pointer", which implies being able to follow it up to outer scopes?  I don't really know about ABIs for languages that support nested functions as a first-class feature, but "static chain" is a term I've heard that's part of that.  e.g. r10 in x86-64 System V is for that; [Raymond Chen summarizes it in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/86886383)

Comment: What would you do in my situation? :)

Comment: I'll let you know when I finish reading the question :P  But it looks like a compiler could just simplify everything by inlining in this case.

Comment: Inlining would simplify it too much, maybe imagine I made a more complex example that didn't make inlining so easy.

Comment: Yeah, that was a tongue-in-cheek comment.  But seriously, does your toy language need to be able to take function pointers to nested functions (or equivalent), e.g. to pass as a callback?  If not, and they can only be called from within the scope of the outer function, the asm implementation doesn't have to look like `enter N, 0` or separate stack frames at all; they can just be syntactic sugar that doesn't use `call` / `ret` in asm.

Comment: For now yeah it doesn't need to to support taking function pointers to nested functions. But just how I wrote it here I would like to be able to call functions within the argument area of the outer function so it's more concise, that's all. I don't know how to translate it to assembly tho.